# Searching a folder for parts of a file's name

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, filesystems, fs

I'm trying to build a media viewing service that automatically downloads new TV show episodes. The problem is, I need to insert a source for the video, and every download has a different structure of the name of the episode. For example:

"Community S01E03", "Community.S01E03.HDTV.PubLisher" or "community.s01e03.1080p".

How can I address this problem? I'm using node.js. Maybe there is some tool that allows to search for file names that contain certain strings?

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Read up a bit on regular expressions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

You can get much of what you want using those plus test() in JS.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("Community", i); //modifier i makes it case insensitive
if (mystring.test(pattern)) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I still have difficulties finding the file, because I can't get a string of file names in a folder...